# r order numeric values

Tags: r, plyr

My question is trivial but some how I cannot find how to sort numbers.  I would like it to be order by group and rank (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,**10,11,12,13,14**)

```
means <- ddply(Data, ~Group ~rank, summarise, mean=mean(Foo))
#My column types
str(means)
#'data.frame':  56 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ Group: chr  "dEC" "dEC" "dEC" "dEC" ...
# $ rank : chr  "1" "10" "11" "12" ...
# $ mean : num  41.4 67.4 NA 65.9 71.3 ...

#means
        Group rank     mean
1         dEC    1 41.37500
2         dEC   10 67.37500
3         dEC   11       NA
4         dEC   12 65.88889
5         dEC   13 71.33333
6         dEC   14 69.87500
7         dEC    2 60.87500
8         dEC    3 65.75000
9         dEC    4 66.00000
10        dEC    5 64.50000
11        dEC    6 70.25000
12        dEC    7 66.75000
13        dEC    8 65.12500
14        dEC    9 68.75000
15 Sham - dEC    1 46.90909
16 Sham - dEC   10 67.54545
17 Sham - dEC   11 68.90909
18 Sham - dEC   12 70.00000
19 Sham - dEC   13 68.36364
20 Sham - dEC   14 71.27273
21 Sham - dEC    2 55.72727
22 Sham - dEC    3 62.09091
23 Sham - dEC    4 61.54545
24 Sham - dEC    5 66.09091
25 Sham - dEC    6 67.63636
26 Sham - dEC    7 66.09091
27 Sham - dEC    8 65.90909
28 Sham - dEC    9 65.81818

#Desired results
#Ordered means

        Group rank     mean
1         dEC    1 41.37500
7         dEC    2 60.87500
8         dEC    3 65.75000
9         dEC    4 66.00000
10        dEC    5 64.50000
11        dEC    6 70.25000
12        dEC    7 66.75000
13        dEC    8 65.12500
14        dEC    9 68.75000
2         dEC   10 67.37500
3         dEC   11       NA
4         dEC   12 65.88889
5         dEC   13 71.33333
6         dEC   14 69.87500
15 Sham - dEC    1 46.90909
21 Sham - dEC    2 55.72727
22 Sham - dEC    3 62.09091
23 Sham - dEC    4 61.54545
24 Sham - dEC    5 66.09091
25 Sham - dEC    6 67.63636
26 Sham - dEC    7 66.09091
27 Sham - dEC    8 65.90909
28 Sham - dEC    9 65.81818
16 Sham - dEC   10 67.54545
17 Sham - dEC   11 68.90909
18 Sham - dEC   12 70.00000
19 Sham - dEC   13 68.36364
20 Sham - dEC   14 71.27273
```

Comment: since you're using `plyr`, take a look at `plyr::arrange`

Comment: Do you have rank as numeric column?.  Otherwise, you can convert it to `numeric` and use `order` i.e. `means[order(means$Group,as.numeric(as.character(means$rank))),]`

Comment: @akrun How can I check that?

Comment: you can check the `str(means)`

Comment: @akrun rank is chr. How could I convert it to num?

Comment: You can try `means[with(means, order(Group,as.numeric(rank))),]`

Comment: @akrun works well. Thanks. I'll accept your answer in 5 minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rank` column was not numeric.  So, we convert that to 'numeric' from 'character' class and `order` the columns 'Group' and 'rank'

```
 means[with(means, order(Group,as.numeric(rank))),]
```

Or another option would be `arrange` from `plyr` (as commented by @Wistar)

```
 library(plyr)
 arrange(means, Group, as.numeric(rank))
```

If we are using `dplyr`, all the steps can be chained together (not tested)

```
 library(dplyr)
 Data %>% 
   group_by(Group, rank) %>%
   summarise(mean=mean(Foo)) %>%
   arrange(Group, as.numeric(rank))
```

Comment: Alternatively, `means = arrange(means, Group, as.numeric(rank))` also works since I used `plyr`.